# How to Faithfully Render Original Formatting in TIBCO Spotfire PPT and PDF Exports?

Tags: formatting, export, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer

After getting a report nicely formatted, the export options nearly always fail to faithfully retain the intended formatting (e.g., bar/line graphs are cramped, not completely visible, partly behind another visualization, not all category axis values are shown, text area filters do not fit as intended, proportions of the visualizations are skewed, etc.), even though I try to minimize/eliminate scroll bars.

Even the web client browser version does not always look as intended.

I have adjusted the .ppt and .pdf export options settings' in many ways, but the exported reports are never satisfactorily formatted.

The software (TIBCO Spotfire Analyst 7.8.0 HF-007) is excellent but the export and sharing options are very limiting and betray the original work. Has anyone had success exporting TIBCO Spotfire reports into PPT and/or PDF formats?

Comment: Mild success and with some limitations that I try to stick within when building reports. What visualization types are you dealing with? Are there a lot of scroll bars? I find that messing with the aspect ration and text size helps but I generally agree, Spotfire as an export tool to PDF/PPT leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @MarkP. I use many types of visualizations, including bar and line graphs, tables, etc. There are rarely any scroll bars in the original Spotfire report, but they usually get added to the exported versions automatically.

Comment: what version of spotfire are you using?

Comment: @niko The version is TIBCO Spotfire Analyst 7.8.0 HF-007.

Comment: Newer versions (I am on 7.14 I believe, but I think it started on 7.10) have much better control of how PDFs in particular get exported. Its not perfect, but it lets you control aspect ration, text size, resolution, etc. All things that can get more information on a page while still looking nice. I do remember having difficulty before this version came out. Still not perfect, but much cleaner.